# Offline fallback for responsive images to largest cached image

Tags: workbox

I have a project using srcset for images. They are all in their own sub-directories similar to:

- /images/**image1**/100.jpg, 200.jpg, 500.jpg, 1000.jpg
- /images/**image2**/100.jpg, 200.jpg, 500.jpg, 1000.jpg

The site uses the different sized images in lists and detailed views. Moving from portrait to landscape for instance will change from 100.jpg to 200.jpg and a detailed view would use 500 or 1000.jpg depending on the viewport size.

Is it possible, in an offline scenario, to have workbox look for what's cached with a URI starting with "/images/image1/" and find the highest numbered file and return that? I would much rather use a smaller (or larger) image instead of a broken one if an offline user changes e.g. from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Here's a custom plugin that [requires Workbox v6](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/releases/tag/v6.0.0), and makes use of the new [`handlerDidError` lifecycle event](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins:%7E:text=latency).-,handlerDidError) to provide a fallback:

```
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

// Replace with your desired cache name.
const imagesCacheName = 'images-cache';

function parseImageNameAndSize(url) {
  const pattern = new RegExp('/([^/]+)/(\\d+)\\.jpg$');
  const [_, name, size] = pattern.exec(url) || [];

  // This will return [undefined, NaN] when there's no match.
  return [name, parseInt(size)];
}

async imageFallback({error, request}) {
  let largestSize = -1;
  let cacheKeyOfLargestImage;

  const [originalName, _] = parseImageNameAndSize(request.url);
  // If the URL doesn't match our RegExp, re-throw the underlying error.
  if (!originalName) {
    throw error;
  }

  const cache = await caches.open(imagesCacheName);
  const cachedRequests = await cache.keys();
  // Iterate through all of the cache entries to find matches:
  for (const cachedRequest of cachedRequests) {
    const [name, size] = parseImageNameAndSize(cachedRequest.url);
    if ((name === originalName) && (size > largestSize)) {
      largestSize = size;
      cacheKeyOfLargestImage = cachedRequest;
    }
  }

  if (cacheKeyOfLargestImage) {
    // If we have the cache key for the largest image that meets
    // the conditions, return the cached response.
    return cache.match(cacheKeyOfLargestImage);
  }

  // If there is no image the cache that satisfies these conditions,
  // re-throw the underlying error.
  throw error;
}

// Now, use the callback as a plugin by associating it with
// handerDidError in the strategy of your choice
// (CacheFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate, etc.):
registerRoute(
  // Match any request whose path ends in .jpg
  ({url}) => url.pathname.endsWith('.jpg'),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: imagesCacheName,
    plugins: [
      {handlerDidError: imageFallback},
      // Add any other plugins you want.
    ],
  })
);
```

(I haven't tested all of this code, but I think it should be close to working. Let me know if you run into issues!)

Note that this plugin will only "kick in" if the original request for the URL can't be satisfied by the given strategy, most likely because you're offline and there's no cache match. If you wanted to configure Workbox so that it *always* used the highest-quality image when it was available in the cache, even when you're online or when there's a cache match for the lower-quality image, it's possible to do that (potentially in a [`cachedResponseWillBeUsed`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins:%7E:text=cachedResponseWillBeUsed,-%3A%20Called) callback). But I think for the specific use case you describe, using the new `handlerDidError` callback is the best approach.

Comment: It works great - and was plug and play. Thanks a million Jeff!

This was the biggest issue I had getting this project to work well offline so now I'll go down the rabbit hole and see if I can get it to always use cache if higher resolutions are already cached.